# Verification: A self-conjugate element in an odd-order finite group is the identity

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

I think I've found a proof of the following, but my proof is horrible, and I feel like I've made a mistake or that I've missed an important principle:

Theorem: Let $G$ be a finite group of odd order and suppose $g \in G$ is conjugate to $g^{-1}$. Then $g = e$.

Proof: Since $g$ is conjugate to its inverse, there is an element $h \in G$ such that $h g = g^{-1} h$.

Form the subgroup $H = \langle g, h\rangle$. Since $H$ consists of words of the form $h^{n_1} g^{n_2} h^{n_2} g^{n_2} \cdots h^{n_k} g^{n_k}$, using the above relation, we can write any element in a unique normal form given by $h^r g^s$ with $r$ and $s$ minimal natural numbers.

Since $h$ is still in $H$, $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are still conjugate in $H$.

Let $a$ be any other element also conjugate to $g$ in $H$. Then $(h^r g^s) a (h^{r} g^{s})^{-1} = h^r g^s a g^{-s}h^{-r} $ for some fixed $r$ and $s$. By shoving the $h$'s across the $g$'s with the relation, we see that $a$ can only be conjugate to $g$ if, when normalized, it does not involve a power of $h$. That is, $a = g^n$ for some $n$.

It can be seen that $g^k$ and $g^{-k}$ are conjugate for all $n$, but since $|G|$ is odd, $g^{k} \neq g^{-k}$ for any $k$ uness $g =e$ (the only element of odd order). So $\{g, g^{-1}\}$ forms a conjugacy class in $H$.

But the size of a conjugacy class must divide the order of the group $H$, which by Lagrange must divide the order of $G$. Since $|G|$ is odd, we must conclude that this class has only a single element, and thus $g = g^{-1}$.

Comment: Here is a outline of alternative argument. $hg=g^{-1}h \Rightarrow h^2g=gh^2$, so $h^2 \in C_G(g)$. Since $G$ is odd order, $h^{2k+1} = e$ for some $k$, but then $h = h^{2k+1}(h^2)^{-k}$ centralizes $g$ and hence $g=g^{-1}$, so $g^2=e$ and then $|G|$ odd implies $g=e$.

Comment: Thank you. That sounds more like the level of complexity the argument should be.